# Incompatible type when returning type in C for inner structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct that I want to statically allocate at compile time but I'm not sure how to return a pointer to the inner structure.

```
typedef struct
{
  int d;
} innerStruct;

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  innerStruct inner;

} myStruct;

static myStruct m1;

innerStruct * getMyStructPtr()
{
  myStruct * ptr = &m1;
  return ptr->inner;
}

int main()
{
  innerStruct * retval = getMyStructPtr();
  return 0;
}
```

Link to online compiler: https://onlinegdb.com/SJAFJCy0Z

Comment: `return &ptr->inner;` ?

Comment: `return &m1.inner;`

Comment: I'd suggest just `return &m1.inner;`, and leave `ptr` out of it altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the data types!!

Your function promised to return a `innerStruct *`, whereas your code attempts to returns a `innerStruct`. They are neither same nor compatible. Fix either and use it appropriately.

Following the function call, it appears that you may want to write

```
 return &(ptr->inner);  // return type innerStruct *
```

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, but not wrong, either, the focus in on the type here, the usage, well, a bit odd, I agree.

Comment: Thanks. I'm making simplified code based on a larger codebase. "ptr" was used to reduce code length. I need to brush up on pointer knowledge.